# key strokes from different keyboards

Tags: keyloggers

when using multiple keyboards, it is possible to use them simultaneously.

However one thing i noticed is that key combinations are also accepted across different keyboards. for example, i connect two keyboards i press *ctrl*-*alt* on one and *del* on another, the input is taken.

Can there be any possible security problems or leverage in this? like, a keylogger can sniff USB packets and insert a stroke without the user noticing it?

Comment: If you've got a keylogger running, this is the least of your problems

Comment: I'm honestly unable to understand what answer you're expecting to receive.

Comment: also this is highly depandend on your local setup. you can setup a system so that this "cross-keybaord" trick does not work. Also, why do you think it requirers USB sniffing. it could just as easily sniff the keyboard buffer or input buffer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not really introduce additional risk, since an attacker has either full keyboard control or no keyboard control at all. If an attacker had only access to the Ctrl key of a keyboard or something like that, he could trick you into performing actions be pressing it at the right time. However, there is not really a situation in which only some keys are available to an attacker.